# Picture taken by intent and saved temp, how to display on imageview?

Tags: android

Trying to figure out how to save image temporary after it was taken by intent. I found this code and it works for me but after I take picture and press ok nothing is showed at imageview. I need those pictures to be taken from camera and shown untill it will be uploaded

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ImageLoading libraries like Glide,Picasso

Comment: I need those pictures to be taken from camera and shown untill it will be uploaded

Comment: My answer will still be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you store image in temp file, you'll be having uri/path of that file.

Then create bitmap image from that file path as :

```
   File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File image = new File(sd+filePath, imageName);
   BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
   bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
```

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Once you get the bitmap, set it to image view.

```
imageView.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
```

You can also use images related library for the same purpose as well. I would recommend `Picasso`, `Glide`, etc.

Comment: Could you help me to implement glide or picasso?